# count characters with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to count characters in textarea as the text is typed in, except anything that is surrounded by { }. I need to print the count below the text area. I've seen a few counters in JavaScript but am not sure how to exclude { enclosed text } from it. Do I do it on click?

```
<textarea id="myInput"></textarea>
Counter: <span id="charCount"></span>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
    $('#charCount').text( this.value.replace(/{.*}/g, '').length );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/8R9DH/

---

The regex that I use is not the best choice. Use the regex literals provided by @Matt or @Pointy.

---

Here:

```
var input = $('#myInput'),
    count = $('#charCount'),
    limit = 10;

input.keyup(function() {
    var n = this.value.replace(/{.*?}/g, '').length;
    if ( n > limit ) {
        this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.length + limit - n);
        n = 10;
    }
    count.text( n );
}).triggerHandler('keyup');
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/8R9DH/2/

Comment: +1 for jsfiddle. Beautiful! thanks. An afterthought... Is there a way to impose a limit, say 200 chars?

Comment: This is the right solution, but the regex match wont work if you want to allow more than one {of} {these} in the {code}.

Comment: Limit based on counting total input minus anything in curly brackets.

Comment: @santa I've updated my answer. The calculation `this.value.length + limit - n` looks confusing, but it works.

Comment: @Šime Vidas Actually, you brought up a good point: I do need to count includes, but based on an assigned value. Say I have 3 includes {i1}, {i2} and {i3} and I know that each would be equal 5, 10 and 15 chars accordingly. I insert them not by typing but by clicking: $(".myInclude").click(function () { var addInclude = $(this).text(); $('#myInput').append(" {" + addInclude + "}"); }); How would I count the total then? Sorry this is getting more complex then I originally envisioned...

Comment: @santa So, you want to limit the textarea value length to 200 characters? So this: `123{456}` would count as 8 characters?

Comment: Let's say 200 chars total. So, 123 {i2} would count as 14 chars (123 plus space) and i2==10.

Comment: @santa I changed the regex to this: `/{|}/g`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/8R9DH/4/ Is this OK?

Comment: Close... I have modified the jsfiddle code to be able to insert text with a click of a div insted of typing. Each insert has a numeric value in it. That value is what each insert should be counted as. I broke the counter though, while changing replace to match and new regex (which I'm not sure is quite correct). I was trying to take an insert string and strip all by numeric value to make it == n. http://jsfiddle.net/HDLUB/2/

Comment: OK, got the value to be counted from each insert: http://jsfiddle.net/HDLUB/13/ Now just need to figure out how to apply that value towards the total char count.

Comment: @Šime Vidas I have closed this question. I really appreciate all your help. I feel like the question has evolved into a next step and I don't feel like I can continue asking you for more revisions.  I posted new question as a separate issue here, in case you'd like to see it, but for now I finally need to get my 6 hrs of sleep and try to give it another whirl:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176442/need-help-to-debug-jquery-char-counter-logic

Answer (score 4):

Something like this. I used `keyup` instead of `change` because the `change` event only fires on a textarea when it loses focus.

```
var $input = $('#myInput'),
    $output = $('#charCount'),
    re_strip = /\{.*?\}/g;

$input.keyup(function ()
{
    var val = $(this).val();
    val = val.replace(re_strip, '');
    $output.text(val.length);
});
```

[Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/UVgP6/)

Comment: You can slim the code: `$output.text( this.value.replace(re_strip, '').length );` 3 lines of code is an overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: @Šime: you're right, but I wanted the code to be readable to the OP, who might not be as experienced as you.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
$('#myInput').change(function() {
  $('#charCount').text(this.value.replace(/{[^}]*}/, '').length);
});
```

Now here's an important thing to know: usually, you count characters in a textarea to prevent overflowing database fields.  Thus it's important to let the user use up all possible characters, but you don't want to cut off anything without warning.  The issue is that IE and other browsers do different things with embedded newlines. I don't remember which is which exactly (I'll figure it out and update the answer), but one/some browsers include CR-LF pairs as line separators, and one/some do not.

*edit* — ok I'm remembering more - the issue is that there's a difference (in some browsers) between the string handed back to JavaScript when you get the `<textarea>` "value" attribute and the string that the browser will actually post back to the host. (Yes really.)  Thus, when you're checking the length, that weird behavior has to be accounted for.  Here's the code I use:

```
var
  adjust = ta.val().match(/[^\r]\n/g),
  alen = adjust ? adjust.length : 0,
  actual = ta.val().length + alen,
  ratio = Math.max(actual/ml);
```

The variable "ta" there is a `<textarea>` DOM element. First, the variable "adjust" is set to the the number of newlines found in the value *without* a preceding carriage return. If there are some found, then that total is subtracted from the plain length of the contents to give "actual", which should be the actual number of characters that the browser would send back to the server if the form were posted.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$("#myInput").change(function(){

n = this.val().length;
$('#charCount').text = n;
});
```

Comment: But how do I exclude text in curly brackets as well as the brackets?

Comment: this might not satisfy the "don't count text enclosed in curly braces" requirement :-)