# Need help to debug jQuery char counter logic

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea with a counter below that counts input characters. There is a maximum input limit set as well. I also added couple of spans that insert values into that textarea too when they are clicked.

```
<span id="tag1" class="tags"></span>
<span id="tag2" class="tags"></span>
<br>
<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea> 
<br>
Counter: <font id="charCount"></font>
```

The content in the spans contains a numeric value, like (10). When the value is inserted into textarea I need the counter to increase by that value and not by the char count in the insert.

Currently some of it works and some not. Need help putting it together. I put my  code here: http://jsfiddle.net/8R9DH/11/

---

EDIT:

Expected behavior:

1. Input into text area can be done via typing in directly or by clicking on of the spans or a combination of both
2. Counter counts all characters up to a max and stop input once the limit is reached
3. Counter counts each character and space entered manually but when an insert is user the counter is increased by the numeric value contained in the include. Eg. 
       ***<text include (5)>*** == 5 or ***<text include (10)>*** == 10
   For example, the following input should be counted as 13 characters:

   ```
   <textarea id="myTextArea">abc <text insert (5)> 123</textarea>
   ```

Comment: What, specifically, is your question?

Comment: It is buggy and does not work like intended.

Comment: That's implied by the question, I think ;)

Comment: @santa: please be more specific. What inputs make it work incorrectly? What do you expect to see (vs. what you actually see) when it works incorrectly?

Comment: @santa: you might need to rephrase your question...please find a way to make it a little bit understandable. I ended up currently guessing what you wanted as a result. :)

Comment: I know if's a bit confusing. I just updated the initial question with more expected behavior.

Comment: What if you have manually entered 44 char, and then clicked on span which inserts more then 6 chars. Should text be trimmed or should be over 50 char?

Comment: So you want to give your users the ability to trick the character counter with pseudo code? Why would you need to do this?

Comment: @nemke If I'm at 44 chars and click to insert 10 more it won't happen because it will be more than the max limit.

Comment: @picardo the inserts are the substitute of estimated inputs, like a value from a database that may have a max length of 10, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your javascript logic. Function called onClick event of the span should also include the logic to update the count correctly. Below would be sample for it.

```
$(".tags").click(function() {
    var insertTag = $(this).text(),
        tagLength = insertTag.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    var n = parseInt(input.val().replace(/{|}/g, '').length) + parseInt(tagLength);
    if ( n <= limit ) {
        input.append(" &lt;" + insertTag + "&gt;");
        count.text( n );
    }
});
```

But this code should be further improved to correctly count the existing  in the text box correctly. Hence

```
input.val().replace(/{|}/g, '').length
```

should be improved to filter out existing  tags separately and calculate the count with other characters in the text box.

Comment: Thanks. I added the counted onclick and it counts well, but it does not insert any longer after typed text... also the tags seem to replace each other's count, while they need to accrue. Same tag can be used more than once. I think I need a way to store total count on any change - insert or type. I update jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/8R9DH/11/